# Cannot read property 'units' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have created a template driven form in angular. But I am getting error as Cannot read property 'units' of undefined. I have created model also. And defined in ts file also. Still getting this error.Any help please.

user-choice.component.html

```
<form name="form" #f="ngForm" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="border mt-2  p-2 pt-4">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="units">
       Please specify the number of units being used: &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
       <input type="number" min="1" max="12" class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 col-form-label" [(ngModel)]="userChoice.units.value" name="units"  >
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

user-choice.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { UserChoice } from './user-choice.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-choice',
  templateUrl: './user-choice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-choice.component.css']
})
export class UserChoice implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  userChoiceModel: UserChoiceModel;


  @Input() unitBase:any;


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

user-choice.model.ts

```
import { BasicSearchModelI } from '../../../../../core/base';

export class UserChoiceModel {
      units: BasicSearchModelI = {
            value: ''

      };
      qty: BasicSearchModelI = {
            value: ''

      };
      desc: BasicSearchModelI = {
            value: ''

      };

}
```

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model name is `userChoiceModel` but in your template, you are using `userChoice`. You need to update the `ngModel` to `[(ngModel)]="userChoiceModel.units.value"`.

Now all you need to do is initialize `userChoiceModel` in your component. What you have done, is just giving it a type but its value is still `undefined`. You can initialize it like so

```js
userChoiceModel: UserChoiceModel = new UserChoiceModel();
```